# Javascript works in chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a simple code

```html
<input type="number" id="integer" pattern="[0-9]" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" />
```

to disallow decimals in number input. The problem is when I run this in Chrome, the arrow keys work fine ( up/down increasing and decreasing, and left/right moving the cursor ). But the keys don't work on Firefox.

How to handle this in firefox ? and why is this happening ?

Comment: Doesn't fix anything but the `<input>` tag does not need or use a closing slash.

Comment: Works for me in FF

Comment: Have you tried keyCode instead of charCode?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that function isn't supported

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeypress